# Can't see other people's changes to private GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, merge, push, collaboration

I've started a private Github repository and given four other Github members collaborative access through the Settings/Collaborators Github menu. However, I can't see any of their changes on the branch that they have been committing to. I believe that their changes have been pushed because I have hooked the repo to a slack page, and slack notifies me when they push to the repo.

Why can't I see/pull their changes?

Comment: If you view the repository on the Github website, do you see their changes?

Comment: Are you familiar with a typical github workflow? Typically each person would have their own public & private repository. You wouldn't see their changes in your public repository (presumably the master) until you pull them from your coworkers public repositories.

Comment: My assumption is that I 'own' the repository and I give others access to modify it. I assume this is what the add collaborator option does. When viewing the repo on the Github website, which is github.com/myusername/myrepo, I only see my changes.